# Typescript ReferenceError: myApp is not defined

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am learning typescript and using very simple code and getting error. I want to declare a global variable but when I try to compile it with ts-node it gives error but with tsc it works fine

File: index.ts

```
declare var myApp : any;
myApp = "test"


// tsc index.ts - WORKS FILE
// ts-node index.ts - ERROR
```

ERROR when using `ts-node index.ts`

```
myApp = "test"
     ^
ReferenceError: myApp is not defined
```

Comment: I guess you have to use it as `window.myApp`

Comment: I cannot it's a node.js app not the window app.